A weird problem related to ModuleNotFound
I do have chainlit package in my conda environment but I can't import it, why?
(base) ➜  Autogen_GraphRAG_Ollama git:(main) pip freeze | grep chainlit                 
chainlit==0.1.0
(base) ➜  Autogen_GraphRAG_Ollama git:(main) ipython
Python 3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:25:29) [Clang 14.0.6 ]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.26.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import chainlit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import chainlit

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chainlit'

I want to know about the reason why this could happened.

Try python -m pip freeze | grep chainlit and then python instead of ipython and check if this produces the same results.

Yes, this problem still exists.

Actually, I did end up solving the problem - I tried creating a virtual environment with 'virtualenv' instead of using Conda and it worked out okay. I'm still not entirely sure what was going on, but thanks for the tip, though!
